# Ansible vault : encrypt password that begins with '-'

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I am trying to encrypt password "-abc" using ansible-vault. It errors out saying "no such option".

Error is given below,

```
$ansible-vault encrypt_string '-abc' 
Usage: ansible-vault encrypt_string [--prompt] [options] string_to_encrypt

ansible-vault: error: no such option: -a
```

Version:
ansible 2.7.7; 
Ubuntu 18

It is a legitimate password used in our system, that begins with '-'.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it takes `-a` as an option. You should use double dash (`--`) which means end of command options.

```
$ansible-vault encrypt_string -- '-abc'
```